# Failed Amazon SQS request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-sqs, guzzle

I am setting up SQS using Amazon's SDK 2 for PHP.

There appears to be very little existing content on the web using the new SDK.

This is the newest Amazon Services SDK built on top of Guzzle.

I am able to successfully:

1. Create queue
2. Get queue URL
3. List all queues
4. Get a queue ARN

But I cannot get any queue attributes or send a message to a queue.

My call to get the queue attributes is:

```
$attr   = $sqs->getQueueAttributes(
    array(
        'QueueUrl'          => 'test_18_16-36-57'
    )
);
```

When attempting to the the queue attributes I get the following response:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.
>
> The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST
>   /100404228159/test_18_16-36-57
>
> content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   host:sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com user-agent:aws-sdk-php2/2.1.0
>   Guzzle/3.1.2 curl/7.22.0 PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5
>   x-amz-date:20130218T213657Z
>
> content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date
>   a70e8dd76245fc6631c1b051623a90752c7cec0cd55fa636000c47ad3d8e4e06'
>
> The String-to-Sign should have been 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20130218T213657Z
>   20130218/us-east-1/sqs/aws4_request
>   7695e40b612379da5025fca80e26ed6c29f95428e244d2b083764d203d369e36'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does upgrading to the latest version fix the issue?

Comment: Based on what you posted, you are using 2.1.0, and the latest version is 2.1.2.

Comment: You're right, in the last few days they updated the SDK.  I had downloaded the SDK Friday, so I didn't think they would have updated it that recently. Bleeding edge, ugh